# Why is $ \sin8t \sin2t = \frac{\cos 6t -\cos 10t}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I would like to ask about equality of this two equations. 
I have equation $\sin(8t)\sin(2t) + \cos(8t)\cos(2t) = \cos(6t)$. For me it's not clear why equality holds. I don't know how to derive this result $\cos (6t)$.

I checked in wolfram alpha alternate form of $\sin(8t) \sin(2t) = \frac{\cos 6t-\cos 10t}{2}$ but I still don't know how this formula is obtained. Which trigonometric substructions, what formulas should I use to get it?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. From
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(a+b)&=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b
\\\cos(a-b)&=\cos a \cos b+\sin a \sin b
\end{align}
$$ one gets
$$
2\sin a \sin b=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)
$$ which might help.

Answer (score 0):

If we write the functions sine and cosine for real numbers in exponential form they are easy to manipulate. We have that

$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\quad\text{and}\quad\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Then

$$\sin(8t)\sin(2t)=\frac{e^{i8t}-e^{-i8t}}{2i}\cdot\frac{e^{i2t}-e^{-i2t}}{2i}=-\frac{e^{i10t}-e^{i6t}-e^{-i6t}+e^{-i10t}}{4}=\\=\frac12\left(\frac{e^{i6t}+e^{-i6t}}2-\frac{e^{i10t}+e^{-i10t}}2\right)=\frac12(\cos(6t)-\cos(10t))$$

Answer (score 0):

$sin(8t)sin(2t) +cos(8t)cos(2t) = cos6t $

$2 sin(a) sin(b) = cos(a-b) - cos(a+b)$

$2 cos(a) cos(b) = cos(a-b) + cos(a+b)$

$sin(8t)sin(2t) = 1/2 [cos(8t-2t) - cos(8t+2t)] = 1/2[$cos(6t)-cos(10t)]$
$
$cos(8t)cos(2t) = 1/2 [cos(8t-2t) + cos(8t+2t)] = 1/2[$cos(6t)+cos(10t)]$

$ 1/2[cos(6t)-cos(10t)]+  1/2[cos(6t)+cos(10t)]= 6cos(6t)$